# Laravel save tickets with changing numbers into database using a controller

Tags: php, laravel, database

**Issue:**
I need to put the amount selected using the `<select>` option into the database. But each of the `<select>` options have a possible different "amount".

**So you have a UI like this:**
Description - Price 50€ - Amount 2
Another Description - Price 20€ - Amount 2

If you click on checkout it looks like this: (screenshot created using `dd($request)`)
[image]

The issue here is that with every new event this `ticket_x` changes, so you can have an event with `ticket_1` and a different one with `ticket_22` or `ticket_75` etc.

**What needs to be done?**
The amount needs to be calculated (added) from all tickets.

So if you have these tickets:

`ticket_5` with an amount of `3` and `ticket_8` with an amount of `5` the final amount saved into the database would need to be `8`

my CheckoutController.php:

```
    // Store data in database
    $checkout = new Checkout();
    $checkout->course_id = $request->course_id;

    // amount is currently hardcoded
    $checkout->amount = '2';
    // todo: grab the correct amount of the tickets as the tickets get renamed with each new event!
    //$checkout->amount = $request->ticket_1;
    $checkout->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $checkout->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $checkout->email = $request->email;
    $checkout->phone = $request->phone;
    $checkout->censored = $request->censored;
    $checkout->save();
```

frontend code:

```
    <select name="{{ 'ticket_' . $ticket->id }}" class="p-2 bg-gray-100 rounded" data-name="{{ $ticket->title }}" data-id="{{ $ticket->id }}" data-price="{{ $ticket->price }}" size="1" x-model="ticket" x-on:change="$store.tickets.add_ticket({{ $ticket->id }}, ticket)" @if ($event->bookable == '1') disabled @endif>
       <option value="0" class="level1">0</option>
            @for ($i = $ticket->min; $i <= $ticket->max; $i++)
           <option value="{{ $i }}" class="level1">{{ $i }}</option>
         @endfor
    </select>
```

how the front-end looks:

[image]

Comment: Might be worthwhile to include your front-end code here, namely the `<select>` element and how you're sending this data to the back-end. Any time you have dynamic fields like that, you could try converting to an array (as hinted at in the answer below). `<select name="tickets[]">`, then `foreach($request->input('tickets') as $amount)`, etc. But hard to say without seeing your front-end code and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @TimLewis I added the front-end code

Comment: Sweet! So yes, and array could fit your needs better. The code in the answer's comment below should actually work: `<select name="ticket_amounts[{{ $ticket->id }}]">`, then in your backend, `foreach($request->input('ticket_amounts') as $ticketId => $ticketAmount)`. In each iteration, the `$ticketId` and `$ticketAmount` would map to the ID of the Ticket and it's amount, as selected from the dropdown.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks. I came up with the array solution and by adding this:  `$checkout->amount = array_sum($request->ticket);`

Comment: Excellent! There wasn't anything wrong with your initial approach per-se, but you would have had to loop over your `$request->input()` array, and find those that were like `ticket_X` (with regex or `Str::startsWith()`, etc) and sum those fields only. This feels much cleaner. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<select name="tickets[]">...</select>`

And after amount can be sum of array values.

Comment: This would change almost nothing to my issue. It is also almost like it is already done?  `<select name="{{ 'ticket_' . $ticket->id }}">`

Comment: try like this  `<select  name="ticket[{{$ticket->id}}]">`